# Using glslang to extract all uniform delcarations in a glsl file?

Tags: c++, gpu, glsl, vulkan

I want to do some glsl parsing, in particular I want to find all uniform declarations, that includes SSBOS, samplers and images.

To my understanding glslang provides access to the AST, meaning it can be a a robust time saver to avoid writing a brittle parser yourself.

However I don't see a lot of documentation for the library on the git [repo](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glslang). There are some unit tests which gives me some generic idea of how it works but I am still not sure how I would iterate over the AST to find the text blocks corresponding to uniforms.

I basically need to export them to a different file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TIntermTraverser` is the way to go.

In practice, you will define your custom traverser class by inheriting `TIntermTraverser`.
For more details, read the doc comments on the top of the definition of `TIntermTraverser`.
`TIntermTraverser` is used globally in the glslang project, so examining how it is used in the project will be a good help to understand the usage.
`glslang/MachineIndependent/intermOut.cpp` is a good starting point, I think.

I wrote the sample code for you, which is shown below.

```cpp
void glslang_refrection(const std::string& fpath) {
    glslang::InitializeProcess();

    {
        auto src = file::read_file(fpath);
        const char* const sources[] = {src.c_str()};
        const int sourceLengths[] = {static_cast<int>(src.size())};
        const char* sourceNames[] = {""};
        const int sources_num = 1;
        const auto shader_stage = EShLanguage::EShLangCompute;

        glslang::TShader shader{shader_stage};
        shader.setStringsWithLengthsAndNames(sources, sourceLengths, sourceNames, sources_num);
        shader.setEnvClient(glslang::EShClientOpenGL, glslang::EShTargetOpenGL_450);
        shader.setEnvTarget(glslang::EShTargetSpv, glslang::EShTargetSpv_1_0);

        TBuiltInResource default_builtin_resources{};
        shader.parse(&default_builtin_resources, 450, ECoreProfile, false, true, EShMsgDefault);

        class RefrectionTraverser : public glslang::TIntermTraverser {
          public:
            virtual void visitSymbol(glslang::TIntermSymbol* symbol) override {
                if (symbol->getQualifier().isUniformOrBuffer()) {
                    auto name = symbol->getName();
                    auto qualifier = symbol->getQualifier();

                    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", name.c_str(),
                            glslang::GetStorageQualifierString(qualifier.storage));

                    if (qualifier.hasLocation()) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "  loc: %d\n", qualifier.layoutLocation);
                    }
                    if (qualifier.hasBinding()) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "  binding: %d\n", qualifier.layoutBinding);
                    }
                    if (qualifier.hasPacking()) {
                        fprintf(stderr, "  packing: %s\n",
                                glslang::TQualifier::getLayoutPackingString(
                                    qualifier.layoutPacking));
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        RefrectionTraverser traverser;

        auto root = shader.getIntermediate()->getTreeRoot();
        root->traverse(&traverser);
    }

    glslang::FinalizeProcess();
}
```

For the following compute shader, you will get the result below.

```c
#version 450 core

layout(std430, binding = 2) buffer TestBuffer {
    int type;
    float value;
};

layout(location = 2) uniform float u_time;

layout(binding = 1, std140) uniform MainBlock { vec3 data; } u_block;

void main() {}
```

```sh
anon@0: buffer
  binding: 2
  packing: std430
u_time: uniform
  loc: 2
u_block: uniform
  binding: 1
  packing: std140
```